# Is the searchFilter specified with my ADLdapAuthenticationProvider correct for my Active Directory structure?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, active-directory, ldap-query

In my Active directory DC, I have a user named  "**Demo User**" inside the OU "**Special Users**" of the domain "**myCompany.co.hk**".

I'm using Spring Security's `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider` to authenticate a user against my AD DC over SSL on port 636.

For this AD structure, the filter I'm using in my Authenticator is:

```
(&(objectCateogry=person)(objectClass=user)(userPrincipalName=Demo User)(memberOf=OU=Special Users,DC=mycompany,DC=co,DC=hk))
```

When I try to login as this user, providing the username and password in the spring form as is stored in AD, I constantly get "**Bad Credentials**" although I know that the credentials are indeed correct, which makes me think that perhaps it is an issue with my base filter which is not able to locate the user correctly.

I'm unable to understand what I need to change with my code to authenticate as this user which already exists in the AD DC, any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Full Code that I'm using is as follows-

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
@Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http
   .authorizeRequests()
   .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
   .and()
   .formLogin();
 }
@Bean
public AuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
  ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider = 
  new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider( "myCompany.co.hk", "ldaps://192.168.1.636");
  activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true); 
  activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.
setSearchFilter("(&(objectCateogry=person)(objectClass=user)(userPrincipalName=Demo User)(memberOf=OU=Special Users,DC=myCompany,DC=co,DC=hk))");
  return activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/ldap/authentication/ad/ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.html#setSearchFilter(java.lang.String))

> The LDAP filter string to search for the user being authenticated. Occurrences of {0} are replaced with the username@domain. Occurrences of {1} are replaced with the username only.
>
> Defaults to: `(&(objectClass=user)(userPrincipalName={0}))`

So the search filter is not supposed find only one user. It should be written find any user who could possibly be allowed to login to your application. So the filter should not be hardcoded with one specific username. (also, the `userPrincipalName` cannot contain spaces and always ends with the domain name, so `userPrincipalName=Demo User` would always be false)

You should be able to delete the `.setSearchFilter()` line and let it use the default filter.

Your other issue is that the `memberOf` attribute only contains the groups that the user is a member of. It doesn't list the OU that the user is in. If you want only users in the `Special Users` OU to be able to login, you need to set the `rootDn` parameter in [the constructor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/ldap/authentication/ad/ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)):

```
ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider = 
new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(
    "myCompany.co.hk", "ldaps://192.168.1.636", "OU=Special Users,DC=myCompany,DC=co,DC=hk"
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, Gabriel, this seems to be exactly what I was missing. I will go the office tomorrow , make the changes you have suggested and let you know how it goes. On a side note, I had hardcoded the username in the filter because this application is designed to explicitly be accessible to that one particular user only and on one else.

Comment: If that user is the only user in that OU, then you're ok. If there are others in that OU that you do not want them to login, then create a group for access to your application and add the user. Then set the filter to return only users in that group, like: `(&(objectClass=user)(userPrincipalName={0})(memberOf=CN=AppGroup,OU=Groups,DC=myCompany,DC=co,DC=hk))`. You don't want to hardcode the username in the filter, because it will return that user even when different credentials are used. It would let everyone login.

Comment: "The userPrincipalName cannot contain spaces" . Is this fixable on the Spring app end or should i have them remove the space?

Comment: I meant that Active Directory won't allow you to set the `userPrincipalName` to a value that contains spaces, but now that I actually check, it will. But the UPN will contain the domain name (for example, `Demo User@myCompany.co.hk`)